# Идентификатор класса в html

Tags: html

Начал изучать html и css, не понимаю в каких случаях можно использовать идентификаторы класса. Слышал, что их можно использовать только один раз

Comment: Идентификатор только раз(на то он идентификатор), класс можно использовать сколько угодно раз

Comment: Идентификатор(ID элемента) должен быть всегда уникальным(например - у нас же не может быть 2 одинаковых ID на двух разных товарах). CSS-классы используйте сколько хотите

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования:

```
<p id="par1">ID можно использовать только для одного элемента (тега)</p>

<p class="paragraphs">А класс сколько угодно раз</p>
<p class="paragraphs">А класс сколько угодно раз</p>
<p class="paragraphs">А класс сколько угодно раз</p>

<style>
#par {
  color: red; // цвет текста
}
.paragraphs {
  color: green; // цвет текста
}
</style>
```

Comment: `id="paragraphs"` -_-